# Duration line and icons on video screen

Tags: android, performance, video, video-editing

Hi sorry for this basic question,
You might have seen video status specifically music videos with a line and duration and play or pauss icon in it..which is obviously icons display not functions..if anyone can tell me how to add such icons in video display using any app for Android.. It would be very helpful.. Thanks

I have searched internet but was not able to locate some helpful material.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.